# Dynamically updating JLabel to display a changing status msg for processing done on clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I want to display a status msg that updates dynamically as and when different stages of processing is reached on the processing triggered on clicking a button. Could you pls help on this. Here is the code that I used, but is not working. It always shows the status msg at the end of the function and not intermediate status msgs while executing.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainApplet extends JApplet {
  JButton gstbtn = new JButton("Connect to Gst Hotspot");
  JButton wifibtn = new JButton("Connect to existing Wifi networks");
  JLabel status = new JLabel();
  JPanel toppanel = null, nwConfigDialog = null;
  final JFrame f= new JFrame();
  JTextField ssidTxt;
  JPasswordField pwdTxt;
  JOptionPane opt;

  public void init() {

    gstbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Gst Hotspot connect workflow triggered");
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        status.setText("");
        toppanel.repaint();
        if(connectToHotSpot()) { //todo: Connect to gst hotspot
                try {
                        status.setText("connected to Local Gst Box Wifi Hotspot");
                        status.repaint();
                        Thread.sleep(20*1000);
                        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                        System.err.println("connect to hotspot: Sleep Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                }
                //showNwConfigDialog(f);
        } else {
                status.setText("Unable to connect to Local Gst Box Wifi Hotspot");
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
        }
      }
    });

    wifibtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Wifi n/w connect workflow triggered");
      }
    });

    toppanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,4,4));
    gstbtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,5));
    wifibtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,5));
    setContentPane(toppanel);
    getContentPane().add(gstbtn);
    getContentPane().add(wifibtn);
    getContentPane().add(status);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker` for a long running task, and consider swapping the `JLabel` for a `JProgressBar`.  Not only can the progress bar show a string, but if the process takes 5 steps, it can show an indication of how much of the entire task is complete for each of the five tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It always shows the status msg at the end of the function and not
>   intermediate status msgs while executing.

This is because this `Thread.sleep()` call is blocking the [Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) which is a single and special thread where Swing components creation/update and event handling is performed, thus causing the GUI be unable to repaint/update itself until this thread is unlocked:

```
gstbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    ...
    Thread.sleep(20*1000);
    ...
}
```

To avoid this issue you should use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to do heavy tasks in a background thread, leaving the EDT free to update the GUI and publishing interim results. There are lot of examples here in SO, just take a look to [swingworker](/questions/tagged/swingworker) tag.

---

#### Side note

Instead of developing a `JApplet` I'd suggest you to develop a Swing application and use [Java Web Start](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml) to distribute/launch your application from the web.